# How to use C#/C++/librdkafka with OIDC and Azure AD as token provider for OAUTHBEARER in apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, producer-consumer

I try to use C# to produce message to Apache Kafka. But I notice there are a config called sasl.login.callback.handler.class which should be configured in kafka producer client. But I can't find the right place to configure it. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

I notice producer client using C# is related to C++/librdkafka. So I add them in titile. I can't find
sasl.login.callback.handler.class in librdkafka(https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md).

Here are my config:

```
private ProducerConfig _config = new ProducerConfig();
_config.BootstrapServers = server;
_config.ClientId = clientId;
_config.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslPlaintext;
_config.SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.OAuthBearer;
_config.SaslOauthbearerClientId = "MyClientId";
_config.SaslOauthbearerClientSecret = "MyClientSecret";
_config.SaslOauthbearerScope = "ServerClientId/.default";
_config.SaslOauthbearerTokenEndpointUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
```

Need find a solution using C#/C++ to produce msg with OAuth AAD token to Apache Kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

librdkafka doesn't need to set sasl.login.callback.handler.class but need to set
sasl.oauthbearer.method to OIDC.

I have tested using C# and it works.

Here are my configs about OAuth AAD:

```
private ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig();
producerConfig.SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.OAuthBearer;
producerConfig.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslPlaintext;
producerConfig.SaslOauthbearerMethod = SaslOauthbearerMethod.Oidc;
producerConfig.SaslOauthbearerClientId = YourClientId;
producerConfig.SaslOauthbearerClientSecret = YourClientSecret;
producerConfig.SaslOauthbearerScope = "ServerTenantId/.default";
producerConfig.SaslOauthbearerTokenEndpointUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
```